# How to sort array of 0 and 1 of length n in O(n) time and O(1) space? And can we generalize this to array of 0, 1, 2, ...?

Tags: sorting

I would like to sort an array of 0 and 1. I have to sort it in linear time and in constant space. How can I do this **without explicitly counting the number of 0 and 1**?

I did something like this:

```
sort(array):
    Q0 = Queue()
    Q1 = Queue()
    for i in (0, n-1):
        if array[i] == 0:
            Q0.push(array[i]) 
        if array[i] == 1:
            Q1.push(array[i])
    j = 0
    while Q0:
        array[j] = Q0.pop()
        j += 1
    while Q1:
        array[j] = Q1.pop()
        j += 1
```

I think my solution is correct and has O(n) time but I am not sure of O(1) space. Any help?

Also, can we generalize the sorting to 0, 1, 2 arrays?

Comment: Your queues take up O(n) space, not O(1).

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's the problem. So do you have any solution?

Comment: Why can't you explicitly count the number of 0s and 1s?

Comment: Count the number of 0s and number of 1s by making one pass over the array, then produce the output based on the counters. I am fairly sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: I cannot count the number of 0 and 1 because the question is like this. I mean the statement of the exercise is like this.

Comment: Here's a hint: Think about maintaining two array indexes, "front" and "back", initialized to 0 and n - 1. Increment "front" until you encounter a "1", and decrement "back" until you encounter a "0". Swap the elements. Then repeat. As for generalizing it, you can do it in two passes. In the first pass, move all 0's to the front, leaving 1's and 2's mixed together at the back. In the second pass, sort the 1's and 2's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is (tested/working) Python:

```
# sort array of length n containing values of only 0 or 1
# in time O(n) and space O(1)

a = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
first = 0
last  = len(a)-1
print a

# note: don't need temp since values are only 0 and 1
while(last>first):
    if a[first] == 1:
        a[first] = a[last]
        a[last]  = 1
        last    -= 1
    else:
        first   += 1

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to swap all the ones to the end of the array and the zeros to the beginning of the array by keeping two pointers. `i` points to the first index that has a `1`.

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
i = 1
for (j = 1 to n)
    if(a[j] == 0)
        swap(a[i], a[j])
        i++
```

Comment: Did you test? First time through i and j =1 so if a[1]==0 swap(a[1],a[1])

Comment: There is nothing wrong in swapping a[1] with itself.

Comment: If `a[1] != 0` at the start of the loop, `i` will never advance, and the loop won't do anything.

Comment: user2357112: you are right. The if statement should be (a[j] == 0) instead of (a[i] == 0). It is fixed now.